# why checkbox is showing always false value

Tags: angularjs

I have html structure like this

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
        <input ng-model="selectAll" id="selectAll" type="checkbox" ng-click="selectAllChange()"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the js code

```
function parentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selectAll = false;

    $scope.selectAllChange = function() {       

        if($scope.selectAll){
            console.log('ttt');
        }
        else
            console.log('fff');       
    }   
}
```

on click of checkbox whether its checked or not, in console I am always getting `fff`
How to know that checkbox was checked or not in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the `ng-model` binds to the `childCtrl`'s scope, but your code inside `parentCtrl` is accessing the scope created by `parentCtrl`.

You could try `this` instead of `$scope` to get scope triggering the function:

```
if(this.selectAll){
```

And use `ng-change` instead.

```
ng-change="selectAllChange()"
```

`click` and `change` events really mean different things: `click` means mouse down and mouse up on the same element, `change` means the value has changed. When you use `ng-click`, `ng-model` **does not update** the underlying value yet.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/za30ReOUYNQeWRV6ftFp?p=preview)